# How do I determine the user's language in Visual C++?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, modern-ui, windows-mui

I've been searching msdn forever now without a straight answer.

Is there a way to simply get the user's language? I don't want to load any resources or anything at this point, I just want to get their language. Is there ANY simple way to do this?

I'm using visual C++,and I'm not using MFC or anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`GetUserDefaultLangID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318134%28VS.85%29.aspx) may be what you're after. Then again, you may really be after [`GetUserPreferredUILanguages`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318139%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

What about [GetUserDefaultUILanguage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318137(VS.85).aspx)?

Word of caution: Never mistake the user's *locale* for their *UI language*. There are already enough broken applications out there.

Comment: The *locale* governs things like how numbers and dates are formatted, what collation is used for string sorting and the like. The *UI language* obviously just specifies what language the user interface is displayed in. Those two things are separate concepts since Windows 2000 on Windows and should be treated like that. I for example use a German locale (customized to use a sane date format [ISO 8601]) and an English UI language (so that I don't have to put up with idiotic translations).

Comment: Considering that you tagged the question with `MUI` I assumed you'd be aware of the difference, though.

Comment: What's the difference between GetUserDefaultUILanguage and GetUserDefaultLangID?

Answer (score 0):

[GetUserDefaultLCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318135%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or [GetUserDefaultLocaleName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318136%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on Vista will return the LCID/locale name of the user's default locale.

You can then use [GetLocaleInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318101%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or [GetLocaleInfoEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318103%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on Vista to get the display name of the locale (either `LOCALE_SENGLISHDISPLAYNAME` for the english name or `LOCALE_SLOCALIZEDDISPLAYNAME` for the localized name).

Comment: That's the locale. Not the language.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way by calling below API.

LCID lcinfo = GetUserDefaultLCID();

The GetUserDefaultLCID function retrieves the user default locale identifier. On single-user systems, the return value is the same as that returned by GetSystemDefaultLCID.

LCID is the Win32 locale identifier of 32-bit value, combining language and sorting identifiers with predefined locale identifiers are.

1. LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT :- which identifies the system default locale; on later versions of Windows, it can be changed via the Control Panel's Default Language setting.
2. LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT :- which identifies the locale of the current user; it can be changed via the Control Panel default locale setting.

An application can retrieve these two predefined locale identifiers by calling the GetSystemDefaultLCID() and GetUserDefaultLCID() functions, respectively. While, The Thread Locale is maintained on application thread basis and uses SetThreadLocale() and GetThreadLocale() to access the value.

Note: Initially, the value of the thread locale is set to the value of the user's default locale.